# Having trouble getting data from a sample api using a c# Console Application

Tags: c#, linq, api, client, xml-serialization

I am trying to create a console application client that can connect to a sample api and display data from it.

Schema: http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd

Feed format example: http://developer.sportsdatallc.com/files/soccer_v2_standings.xml

The class file generated from the schema is quite large but I'll give an example of an instance I try get output for an attribute of a class.

Class file from schema

```
    public partial class simpleTeam {

    private string idField;

    private string aliasField;

    private string nameField;

    private string country_codeField;

    private string countryField;

    private teamType typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string alias {
        get {
            return this.aliasField;
        }
        set {
            this.aliasField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string country_code {
        get {
            return this.country_codeField;
        }
        set {
            this.country_codeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string country {
        get {
            return this.countryField;
        }
        set {
            this.countryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public teamType type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my client class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UpdateUefaClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Run()
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress =
                        new Uri("http://api.sportsdatallc.org/soccer-t2/eu/teams/standing.xml?api_key="my key to get the live feed(same as feed format)");
                        // base URL for API Controller i.e. RESTFul service

                    // add an Accept header for JSON
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    // 1


                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(""); // accessing the Result property blocks
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // 200.299
                    {
                        // read result 
                        var team = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<simpleTeam>>();
                        foreach (var t in team)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(t.id);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode + " " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Run().Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

After running it I get the following

```
    System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 12
1. Expecting element 'ArrayOfsimpleTeam' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacont
ract.org/2004/07/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'standings', namespace 'ht
tp://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/soccer/sr/v2/teams-standing.xsd'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(Xml
ReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataCo
ntractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleException
s(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver data
ContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader r
eader)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass3.<ReadF
romStreamAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at UpdateUefaClient.Program.<Run>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Daniel\Documents
\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UpdateUefaClient\UpdateUefaClient\Program.cs:line 3
3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have tried the simplest sample (id) but that gives me an error. Not sure what is wrong. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated

Comment: Seems you missed a bit there.  You dont mention the error you receive, or what you get after running it.

Comment: What is following ? you forgot to mention the error

Comment: Sorry @paqogomez edited there

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse team data, but you are pulling the standings feed.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert McKee is right. You are deserializing `standings` not `simpleTeam`.

```
private static standings WebDeserialize()
{
  standings s = null;
  var srlz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(standings));
  //
  var uri = "http://developer.sportsdatallc.com/files/soccer_v2_standings.xml";
  var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create (uri);
  s = (standings)srlz.Deserialize(xmlReader);
  return s;
}

static async Task AsyncWebDeserialize()
{
  Task<standings> task = Task.Run<standings>(() => WebDeserialize());
  standings s = await task;
  Console.WriteLine("Cat:{0} Gen:{1}", s.categories.Length, s.generated);
}
```

Call this like: `AsyncWebDeserialize().Wait()`